# Store metadata for a spreadsheetgear cell

Tags: spreadsheetgear

Is there a way to store custom metadata for a Cell using the SpreadsheetGear control? I need the metadata to persist when saved to an XLSX file. (I am wanting to store some data binding information which is basically an arbitrary string). I could use a comment, but that is not the optimal because it shows a visual marker.

Similarly, is there a way to store custom metadata for a WorkSheet or WorkBook? A Chart?

Could I use an excel SmartTag? (I don't see Spreadsheetgear support for SmartTags).

- Joseph

Comment: no solution yet. But I have an idea: use the Microsoft OpenXml libraries to store the metadata in a property of the spreadsheet.

Comment: I'm also interested in how to store metadata to cells. I need it for mapping cell values+formulas to back-end database. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

To store metadata for my  [spreadsheetgear reporting application](http://mytracefinder.com/plugins/reporting/getting-started/), I save a .metadata file along with the .xlsx file. I keep a dictionary of metadata for each image on the spreadsheet with the key being the image ID. I also keep metadata for each worksheet with the name of the worksheet being the key. This upside is that you can store any arbitrary metadata, the downside is that you have to keep the two in sync (for example if an image gets deleted or a worksheet gets renamed).